# System.IO.StreamWrite and Spanish Characters

Tags: c#, text, encoding, character-encoding

I need to write the following string to a txt a File:

SEGS,AUS1,1,0,0,712205,584,8659094,2,NUÑEZ   FELIX ARTURO,584

I when I use:

```
using  (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@fileSobrantes, true)) {
       sw.WriteLine("SEGS,AUS1,1,0,0,712205,584,8659094,2,NUÑEZ   FELIX ARTURO,584");
}
```

I get this in the file

SEGS,AUS1,1,0,0,712205,584,8659094,2,NUÃ‘EZ   FELIX ARTURO,584

I try with the Encoding parameters in ASCII, UNICODE and ALL UTF and does not work.

```
System.IO.StreamWriter(@fileSobrantes, true,Encoding.UTF32 ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily (and accurately) represent what you get in the file without giving a hex dump. What are you trying to use to read the file? My guess is that if you try `Encoding.Default` that will work for you, but it's hard to say for sure without knowing what you're trying to use to read it.

The other alternative is that your *source* string is incorrect. If you've really got it as a string literal in your source code, are you sure you've got Visual Studio set up to interpret it correctly?

See my [unicode debugging page](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/debuggingunicode.html) for suggested techniques.

EDIT: By the way, why are you prefixing `fileSobrantes` with `@`? For identifiers you only need to do that if they're keywords. You may be getting confused with verbatim string literals - but this isn't a string literal, it's a variable name.

Comment: The @fileSobrantes is because I had something like this "c:\tmp\files" and when I did the refactoring I forgot to delete the @. Thanks

Comment: No problem - glad the answer helped. What was wrong in the end?

Comment: I use the Encoding.Default and now I can open in Excel, Word and WordPad correctly. If I open en notepad or UltraEdit I get the wrong characters. But I need it to open in Excel. Thanks

Comment: Okay. I'd suggest writing in UTF-8 and working out how to tell Excel that it really is using UTF-8, but if what you've got works for you, then that's fine :)